# Prove the Stack-Turing Machine is equivalent to the Classic TM

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines, automata-theory

Consider a “Stack-Turing Machine” variant that operates with one infinite tape and one stack. At each step through the tape, the machine reads the input from the current tape location and from the top of the stack, and then transitions states, writes to the tape, and moves along the tape (like a classic TM) and also can pop from and/or push to the stack (like a classic PDA). In other words: the classic TM has transition function: ( , ) → ( , ,  ∪ ) where q is state, a and b are input/output for tape the classic PDA has transition function: ( , ) → ( , ) where q is state, c is initial top of stack, and d is newly pushed top of stack the stack-TM has transition function ( , , ) → ( , ,  ∪ , ) merging TM and PDA Prove the Stack-Turing Machine is equivalent to the Classic TM.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaCrs.jpg)
Not sure how to approach this.

No Code Involved; theory of computation Proof.

None, this is a theory of computation Proof.

Answer (score 1):

A Stack-TM can simulate a regular TM by simply doing nothing interesting with the stack. A two-tape TM can simulate a Stack-TM by treating the second tape as a stack (only writing to the end and reading from the end by clearing off a symbol). Finally, a regular TM can simulate a two-tape TM since we know that multi-tape TMs are equivalent to single-tape TMs (assuming we know this result). Due to transitivity of the simulation relationship, all the systems are equivalent in that they can all simulate each other.